# Generate a JSON from two string arrays using Gson

Tags: json, gson

Given two array of strings, I would like to parse them with the following structure: {"key1":"value1","key2:value2"}.

Something like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String[] strings1 = {"abc", "def", " ghi"};
String[] strings2 = {"123", "456", "789"};

// Parse it ??
```

Result:

```
Json -> {"abc":"123","def":"456","ghi":"789"}
```

How I can do that?

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I've used the Sachin Gupta solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this (`Gson` only solution):

```
String[] strings1 = { "abc", "def", " ghi" };
String[] strings2 = { "123", "456", "789" };
JsonObject json = new JsonObject();

for (int i = 0; i < strings1.length; i++) {
    json.addProperty(strings1[i], strings2[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by using a simple HashMap . cheers :)

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>;
Gson gson = new Gson();
String[] strings1 = {"abc", "def", " ghi"};
String[] strings2 = {"123", "456", "789"};    
for( int i=0; i<strings1.length; i++){
   map.put(strings1[i],strings2[i]);    
}
String json=gson.toJson(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String[] strings1 = {"abc", "def", " ghi"};
String[] strings2 = {"123", "456", "789"};

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
if(strings1.length == strings2.length){
for(int i=0;i<strings1.length;i++){
   obj.put(strings1[i],strings2[i]);
 }
}
```

Comment: As his tags suggest, he is using `gson`.

Answer (score 1):

Import are given below :

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
```

Code is given below :

```
String[] strings1 = { "abc", "def", " ghi" };
String[] strings2 = { "123", "456", "789" };
JsonObject jObj = new JsonObject();
for (int i = 0; i < strings1.length; i++) {
    jObj.addProperty(strings1[i], strings2[i]);
}
System.out.println("jObj : " + jObj);
```

Comment: Why are you adding for each elem in string1 all string2??

Comment: @Lechucico What do you mean? I am unable to understand.

Comment: @Lechucico Is anything wrong in my code? Is this not working for you?

Comment: I was asking the folowing JSON: {A1:B1,A2:B2,A3:B3}. With that code you'r producing: {A1:B1,A1:B2,A1:B3,A2:B1...}

Comment: @Lechucico Sorry for the typo. I just update my answer.

Comment: @Lechucico Thanks for notify me.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
  public static String constructJSON(String[] tag, String[] status) {
   GSON obj = new GSON();
    try {
        obj.put(tag[0], status[0]);
        obj.put(tag[1], status[1]);
          .................................................
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
     return obj.toString();
}
```

Comment: He is using `gson`

Comment: Edited for gson

Comment: There is no such thing like `GSONObject` at least in Gson. Please read the question carefully.